# Quando uma lista ordenada deve ser, de fato, uma lista ordenada no HTML?

Tags: html, semântica

No HTML existem dois elementos básicos para se definir uma lista:

- [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol), que representa uma lista ordenada;
- [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), que representa uma lista desordenada;

Mas quando, de fato, faz sentido representar uma lista ordenada/desordenada com tais elementos?

Por exemplo, a lista de perguntas na página inicial do Stack Overflow fica organizada de forma ordenada com base na data da última alteração, da mais recente para a mais antiga. Ao meu ver, isso representa uma lista ordenada, pois inverter a posição de diferentes perguntas dentro da lista quebraria a condição de ordem. Avaliando o [código fonte da página](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou59A.png), percebi que o site utiliza `<div>` para representar a estrutura, sem nenhum atributo que auxiliasse na definição da ordem.

Analisando a estrutura apenas pelo código é impossível definir que as perguntas possuem tal ordenação, diferente se fossem estruturadas dentro de um elemento `<ol>`, onde deixaria explicito que a ordenação existe.

Além deste exemplo, poderia citar muitos outros: lista de publicações em um blog, lista de produtos em uma loja virtual - que poderia estar ordenada por preço, popularidade, vendas, etc. Dentre todos, é difícil ver uma página que define tais estruturas com base nos elementos `<ol>` ou `<ul>`.

1. Existe algum motivo que faça ser inviável criar tal estrutura?
2. Utilizar a `<div>` para representar os elementos não quebra a semântica, visto que não transpassa a ideia de ordenação?

Comment: Ao meu ver, quase todos os dados dinâmicos serão mostrados como tabela ou como lista, na segunda opção geralmente se usa `div`, mas também pode se usar `section` ou `article` que são mais específicas. O não uso de listas deve-se, provavelmente, as facilidades de uma div (não ter que retirar o marcador, margens internas e externas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## UL vs OL

**UL**

UL é um conjunto de elementos onde a ordem não importar para o entendimento do conteúdo, ou seja, independente da ordenação desses elementos o usuário sempre será capaz de entende-lo. **Ex.** Imagina a NetShoes onde vc pode ordenar uma lista de itens por valor, cor ou marca. A ordem desses itens não interfere no entendimento do conteúdo, então para esse tipo de conteúdo uma UL (lista "desordenada") seria o mais indicado. Acredito que qualquer tipo de lista que tenha um filtro, ou seja, uma lista de elementos que possa ser rearranjada de acordo com o que o usuário deseja, deva ser tratada como um UL.

> Por exemplo, a lista de perguntas na página inicial do Stack Overflow
> fica organizada de forma ordenada com base na data da última
> alteração, da mais recente para a mais antiga. Ao meu ver, isso
> representa uma lista ordenada...

A lista de perguntas do StackOverflow seria o caso de uma lista não ordenada, uma UL, pois é uma lista onde a ordem não é rígida, inclusive vc não pode ter uma lista Ordenada que cada hora o usuário pode fazer um filtro mudando a ordem ao seu gosto, por exemplo de Data para Ativas ou Sem Resposta. Logo as respostas não precisam respeitar uma ordem para o entendimento, e cada Pergunta pode ser vista como um elemento único, como os Tênis no caso da NetShoes, são elementos do mesmo grupo, mas não necessariamente precisam de uma ordem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OL**

OL é uma lista ordenada, a ordem do conteúdo dessa lista está diretamente ligado a forma como o usuário vai entender a mensagem, e alterar a ordem dessa lista pode afetar diretamente no entendimento do conteúdo.

Nesse tipo de lista os elementos têm uma ordem fixa que não deve ser ser alterada, e geralmente não apresentam filtros ou outros artifícios para reordenação do conteúdo. Ex. o Índice de um Livro ou a Receita de um Bolo, a ordem de preparo do Bolo por exemplo é uma lista de tarefes que deve ser cumprida a risca. Assim como alterar a ordem dos capítulos de um Livro pode deixar o usuário completamente perdido na história. Então para esse tipo de conteúdo a Lista Ordenada OL é o mais indicado, pois exite uma linearidade regida na ordem do conteúdo e dos elementos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Visto a imagem percebe-se que todos os passos do modo de preparo pertencem a um mesmo grupo, porém esses elementos precisam estar em uma determinada ordem para fazerem sentido para o usuário. Pensando justamente na listagem de perguntas da StackOverflow a OL não seria o ideal, pois o conteúdo independe da ordem para fazer sentido, além disso é uma lista que o próprio usuário pode determinar a ordenação do conteúdo, o que não justificaria o uso de uma OL.

**A lado Semântico da história:**

Agora que já ficou claro o que é e quando deve ser usado cada tipo de listagem pense na semântica das coisas. Imagine um leitores de tela de um usuário deficiente visual, ou um bot de mecanismo de busca como o Google. Essas duas personas não usam a visão para interpretar o conteúdo que estão acessando. Um listagem com um conjunto de tenis pode ser indexada em qualquer ordem. Já um listagem com o passo a passo de uma determinada tarefa deve ser seguida em uma determinada ordem imutável. Logo se vc declara um procedimento de cadastro usando uma UL, certamente o *crawler* de pesquisa ou o usuário deficiente visual teriam dificuldades para seguir a ordem correta das coisas, semanticamente nesse caso a OL faria mais sentido para um software que lê o código da página para o usuário.

Essa lista tem que seguir uma ordem imutável:

```
<ol>
    <li>Bata as claras em neve e reserve</li>
    <li>Misture as gemas, a margarina e o açúcar até obter uma massa homogênea</li>
    <li>Acrescente o leite e a farinha de trigo aos poucos, sem parar de bater</li>
    <li>Por último, adicione as claras em neve e o fermento</li>
    <li>Despeje a massa em uma forma grande de furo central untada e enfarinhada</li>
</ol>
```

Essa lista não necessita de ser ordenada, e inclusive pode ser reordenada sem prejudicar o entendimento do conteúdo.

```
<ul>
    <li>Tênis Kappa Impact Masculino</li>
    <li>Tênis Mizuno Jet 2 N Masculino</li>
    <li>Tênis Asics Patriot 8 Masculino</li>
    <li>Tênis Olympikus Spirit 2 Masculino</li>
</ul>
```

O estilo padrão do CSS dos diferentes tipo de listagem ajudam o usuário a compreender o tipo de conteúdo que está acessando. Uma lista não ordenada não precisa de numeração para ordenar os elementos do conjunto, pois essa ordem pouco importa para o usuário. Já uma lista ordenada é numerada, justamente para auxiliar o usuário a entender que ali existe uma ordem semântica das coisas, e os elementos devem seguir uma determinada ordem.

---

## Grid View vs List View

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que vc sempre deve levar em consideração o conteúdo que sera apresentado para o usuário e como esse conteúdo deve ser tratado para oferecer a melhor experiencia de uso para quem acessa a informação. Um exemplo disso é por exemplo formatar o conteúdo em um `List View` ou em um `Grid View`. Acredito que é aqui que a maioria das pessoas escolhem entre usar uma estrutura de Lista semântica `UL/OL` ou um sistema de *Grid* com `Divs`, A vantagem de se usar `Divs` é que vc não precisa remover o css padrão do `user-agente` das listas (bullets e números), no entanto vc perde o valor semântico do conjunto de elementos que pertencem a mesma lista.

Se vc vai listar os Tênis da NetShoes para o cliente o *Grid View* vai ser uma experiencia mais agradável para o usuário. Já para o modo de preparo do Bolo uma listagem tipo *List View* faria mais sentido do que um Grid.

***Mas como podemos usar um Grid View para uma Lista Ordena?***

Vário exemplos disso vc pode encontrar em Manuais de Montagem, Diagramas, etc. Veja que nessa imagem temos uma Lista Ordena exibida em forma de *Grid View*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Pontos a considerar:* Independente de ser um Grid ou Lista, pense na experiencia do usuário (UX), e em qual será a melhor forma de passar esse conteúdo. No exemplo acima, com um avião caindo, é pouco provável que alguém tenha tempo para ler algo, além do mais cado passageiro pode falar uma língua diferente... Então uma listagem com imagem é um modelo ótimo para essa situação. Sempre se coloque no lado do usuário e sempre tenha a semântica em mente. Até pq o Google considera isso como boa prática e pode interferir até no [SEO e rankeamento do seu site](https://searchengineland.com/technical-seo-age-semantic-search-290791.)

Artigo de referência onde vc pode ver as vantagens e desvantagens do ***Grid View vs List View***: https://uxplanet.org/mobile-ux-design-list-view-and-grid-view-8f129b56fd5b

**Fator FrameWork**

Muitas vezes, principalmente em *Frameworks* que possuem Grids como o Bootstrap, Foundation ou Materialize precisamos distribuir nosso conteúdo em `Rows` e `Cols`, para pessoas que não têm experiencia com CSS fica inviável construir um *Grid View* com `UL/LI` que siga a responsividade do *Grid System*, acredito que por isso vemos muitas listas construídas com `Divs` até hoje...

Aqui por exemplo tem um exemplo de lista semântica construida com UL/LI usando o Grid do Boostrap.

```css
[class*="col-"] {
 border: 1px solid red !important;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> conteúdo dentro de li </li>
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> conteúdo dentro de li </li>
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> conteúdo dentro de li </li>
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> conteúdo dentro de li </li>
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> conteúdo dentro de li </li>
    <li class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> conteúdo dentro de li </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**DIV List e Acessibilidade**

Em último caso, em uma situação onde vc não tenha a opção de optar por Listas e tenha que exibir seu conteúdo em `Divs` vc pode usar os atributos `role` para indicar aos leitores de tela que esse conjunto de `divs` deve ser interpretado como uma lista. Para isso declare a div *container* como `role="list"` e os itens internos como `role="listitem"` .

Assim a semântica e acessibilidade fica mais claras, apesar de que não podemos garantir como os leitores de tela vão tratar esse conteúdo, visto que os atributos `role` ainda não são um padrão oficial e com suporte total tando dos browser quanto dos leitores de tela. Vc pode se informar mais sobre esse atributo na documentação oficial da W3C: https://www.w3.org/wiki/PF/XTech/HTML5/RoleAttribute

Exemplo de listagem semântica feita com `div`:

```
<div role="list">
  <div role="listitem">dog</div>
  <div role="listitem">cat</div>
  <div role="listitem">sparrow</div>
  <div role="listitem">wolf!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente resposta @hugocsl, a única coisa que eu alteraria seria a palavra `cego` por `deficiente visual`, visto que nem todos os usuários que utilizam leitores de tela são necessariamente cegos... mas é claro, isso é apenas uma tecnicalidade que não afeta a qualidade da resposta. Crítica construtiva man..

Comment: @fernandosavio com toda razão!